# How do I link to Qwt libraries on Ubuntu?

Tags: c++, linux, qt, linker-errors, qwt

I have installed the Qwt library on Ubuntu 10.04. The Qwt plotting widgets have appeared in QtCreator but when I try to use any of them I get the error:

> "qwt_plot.h" no such file or directory.

Can anyone help?

**Edit:** 
I've solved this by implementing [Begemoth's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5801379/594137) as follows:

1. Open the project file (`.pro`)
2. Add the following lines to the bottom of the file:
   `INCLUDEPATH += /usr/include/qwt-qt4`
   `LIBS += -l qwt-qt4`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ubutu like Debian provides several versions of qwt (for qt4 and qt3), so include files for qwt reside in `/usr/include/qwt-qt3` or `/usr/include/qwt-qt4` directory, you need to add this directory to the list of the include search path, e.g. with `-I` gcc flag.

PS: I assume that you have installed the development package for qwt (libqwt5-qt4-dev).

Comment: Thanks, I have found the qwt-qt4 directory with the same path as you stated. But I do not know how to add this directory to the list of the include search path. Sorry I am a pain.

Comment: Yes, "libqwt5-qt4-dev" is installed.